# Deserialize XML File into DTO

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm trying to import an XML file into a DTO.

Example Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<treffer>
    <prod_internid>123456789</prod_internid>
    <md_nr>56642</md_nr>
    <md_mart_id>4</md_mart_id>
    <md_mart_bez>Twitter</md_mart_bez>
</treffer>
```

Xml Dtos

```
[XmlRoot("treffer")]
public class DeAnalyseArtikelXmlDto
{
    [XmlElement("prod_internid")]
    public long ArtikelId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("md_nr")]
    public int MedienNr { get; set; }

    public DeMedienArtXmlDto MedienArt { get; set; }

}

[XmlRoot("treffer")]
public class DeMedienArtXmlDto
{
    [XmlElement("md_mart_bez")]
    public string Bezeichnung { get; set; }
}
```

Importer:

```
public  bool Import()
{
    DeserializeXMLFileToObject<DeAnalyseArtikelXmlDto>("C:\\temp\\xml\\toImport.xml");
    return true;
}


public static T DeserializeXMLFileToObject<T>(string XmlFilename)
{
    T returnObject = default(T);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(XmlFilename)) return default(T);

    try
    {
        StreamReader xmlStream = new StreamReader(XmlFilename);
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        returnObject = (T)serializer.Deserialize(xmlStream);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       // ExceptionLogger.WriteExceptionToConsole(ex, DateTime.Now);
    }
    return returnObject;
}
```

It works for the properties ArtikelId and MedienNr but the property DeMedienArtXmlDto stays null (even tho the properties of the DeMedienArtXmlDto are annotated themselves...)

Am I doing something wrong that it doesn't fill this property?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How should your program know, that `md_mart_bez` should serialize to `MedienArt`? You have to indicate this by adding the appropriate `XmlElement`:

```
[XmlRoot("treffer")]
public class DeAnalyseArtikelXmlDto
{
    [XmlElement("prod_internid")]
    public long ArtikelId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("md_nr")]
    public int MedienNr { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("md_mart_bez")]
    public DeMedienArtXmlDto MedienArt { get; set; }    
}
```

Instead of using a class that wraps a `Bezeichnung`, why not just put the string directly into your parent class? Alternativly use an `enum` that contains the different values for `MedienArt`.

```
public enum DeMedienArtXmlDto
{
    [XmlEnum("md_mart_bez")]
    public Art1
}
```